# Displaying my current location

Tags: java, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm using Android studio to make a basic google maps app and one of the first things I need to do is to display my current location as soon as the app opens up. I'm using the Google Maps activity template and I've replaced the Sydney dummy coordinate function with one from the Google Maps API guide page and it still isn't doing the trick. I'd really appreciate some help to get me going.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have location permissions, but I believe what you are looking for is relatively simple by implementing the interfaces `OnMyLocationButtonClickListener` and `OnMyLocationClickListener`. Check out the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/location#the_my_location_layer)

Answer (score 0):

You need to get FusedLocationProviderClient:

```
FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient = 
LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
```

and try this:

```
private void getDeviceLocation() {
        try {
            if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
                Task locationResult = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
                locationResult.addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {

                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            imHere = (Location) task.getResult();

                            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(imHere.getLatitude(), imHere.getLongitude());
                            MarkerOptions markerOptions = getMarkerOptions(latLng, "You here",
                                    BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));

                            imHereMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, DEFAULT_ZOOM));



                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Current location is null. Using defaults.");
                            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: %s", task.getException());
                            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mDefaultLocation, DEFAULT_ZOOM));
                            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch(SecurityException e)  {
            Log.e("Exception: %s", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```